# should i limit my c# source generator to only find partial types?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, sourcegenerators

done a couple c# source generators.  In all my cases i wanted to enhance an existing type so it needed to be marked as partial.  also in these cases i mark what types i expect generation on by adding an attribute to the type.

I added a condition to my predicate of CreateSyntaxProvider of

```
rds.Modifiers.IndexOf(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword) > -1
```

so i only target syntax nodes that include the partial modifier.  However, sometimes other devs when adding the attribute to a type are frustrated that it's not working because they forgot to make their type partial.

I thought maybe i could make my attribute only target partial types...but that doesn't seem to be an option.  What's the guidance from microsoft here, should i:

- not restrict to partial and add the generated code and let the compiler complain to the user that the type isn't partial? (this leads to a error that most won't understand)
- emit some kind of error in my IIncrementalGenerator
- leave my check in place and tell other devs to RTFM?
- skip all that and just profit AKA something else?

looking for any docs/articles for best practices in this space

Comment: This is something very opinionated. My "personal" preference is to add the generated code and the compiler will let the developer knows that he forgot "partial" modifier.

Answer (score 3):

> emit some kind of error in my IIncrementalGenerator

You can emit diagnostics from an incremental generator -- rather than putting the source file in the SourceProductionContext, you can emit a diagnostic. That's absolutely intended for scenarios like this where the user's code isn't quite right enough.